# understanding fqdns is troubling

Tags: webserver, domain, hostname

I am struggling to understand the FQDN for servers.

At the moment mine is just localhost if i type hostname in to my server terminal it just says localhost.

I understand you need a different one from this if you want to set up cpanel, or postfix or anything really.

As i know its comprised of two parts:

hostname.domainname

can domain name be made up, or does it have to be one of your domains that is set up for use on your server?

and host name can be anything, or it has to be the servername? and does it have to be set up as a sub domain of the domain?

I hope you understand my issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"FQDN" stands for "Fully qualified domain name". That is, it simply is a complete domain name that you could look up in DNS without any further additions. So, yes, "domainname" should be a real domain owned by you.

How exactly the FQDN is composed, though, depends on where it needs to be used – some places just require something that's resolvable by DNS, while others prefer a more specific one.

For example, you'd usually have a *primary* or *canonical* FQDN that refers to the server itself, so it *should* have the server's hostname in it, e.g. `wildebeest.gnu.org` (although that's probably rarely required, simply avoids confusion). At the same time, more FQDNs can point at it, for specific services; e.g. `www.gnu.org` or just `gnu.org`.